# Get Parameters Before The URL

Tags: php, curl, parameters, get, encode

I receive a string like this:

```
result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD
```

I use this code to encode the url:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD"); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$raw = rawurldecode($output);
$pars = parse_url($raw);
parse_str($pars['query'],$result);
```

I'v seen that with the function `parse_str()` I can't get the parameters before `&url=`. How I can get the `response=OK`? I need it to know if my website can go forward with an operation.

As someone has asked, this is

```
var_dump($raw) -> string(112) "result=OK&token=330852&url=https://www.premiumline.eu/onshop/vas/login_mp?token=330852&acq=225583&track=12yy2333"
```

Thanks before!

Comment: The question mark might cause you some trouble

Comment: That is not a correctly encoded query string. Can you post `var_dump`'s of the different values (`$output`, `$raw`, etc.)?

Comment: @jeroen added at the original post!

Comment: You're going to have to url-encode what's after the url= part

Comment: And `$output`? That is likely where your problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've seen that with the function `parse_str()` I can't get the
>   parameters before `&url=`

**Not true**

---

You can use [parse_str()](https://php.net/parse_str) to parse all parameters of a query string, i.e.:

```
$queryStr = "result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD";
parse_str($queryStr);
echo $result;
echo $token;
echo $url;
```

---

**Output:**

```
OK
ABCD
http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD
```

---

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/WaSufn)

Comment: Thank you! It works! My fault was "parse_url()" before of "parse_string()".

Answer (score 1):

Encode the questionmark to `%3F` .
Only 1 questionmark is allowed in a url (it is a delimeter).

`$the_url = urlencode($url);`

```
$str = "result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD";

$params =  parse_str(urlencode($str));
$result = $params['result'];
```

Comment: I see only a question mark on the url. Where is the 2nd?

Comment: agree with this answer, you'll get only second token parameter

Comment: Okay, so how I can get also the first parameter?

Comment: there are 2 questionmarks, because you left out the first part of the url, it is something like 'http://domain.com?result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD' , which is not allowed, so you should encode the last questionmark.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the exact value of `$output`, I would guess that this is the problem:

```
$raw = rawurldecode($output);
```

Here you are decoding your string, converting a valid query string into an undecoded string.

As you want to parse the result as a query string - using `parse_str()` - you should not decode it first as after decoding it no longer contains valid input for `parse_str()`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP gets as QUERY_STRING, string **after last question mark**, so you have your own '?' and one in 'url' parameter, that's why you're receiving only token, and the one!

at first encode this to avoid from url characters in your string
`result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD`

Example

```
$urlParam = "result=OK&token=ABCD&url=http://www.example.com/shopping/vas?token=ABCD";

$urlParamEncoded = urlencode($urlParam);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlParamEncoded); 

//return the transfer as a string 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

// $output contains the output string 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$raw = rawurldecode($output);
$pars = parse_url($raw);
parse_str($pars['query'],$result);
```

Then you can use `urldecode` in your destination script file.